# keypress vs keyup crossbrowser IPAD

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to move my cursor from one input to an other when i type a character.

HTML:

```
<div class="div-word">
   R
   <input class="input-letter" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
   V
   <input class="input-letter" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
   È
   <input class="input-letter" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
   E
```

JS:

```
$('.input-letter').on('keypress', function (e){
    $(this).next('.input-letter').focus();  
});
```

first, i used the event "keyup" but the event is not detected on Ipad so i used "keypress". The problem is that IE will trigger the event before inserted the character and the character will be insert in the next input.

so i try a not so good fix like this :

```
$('.input-letter').on('keypress', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(code));
    $(this).next('.input-letter').focus(); 
});
```

this work but i also need to catch the "change" event on each input and the preventDefault canceled it.

any idea ?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9eU4E/

Comment: you can give https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/ a go